# Typescript optional parameters overload

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

I have a class e.g.

```
class SomeClass {
   someMethod(param1: string; param2?: string) { ... }
}
```

And another one that extends from fore

```
class AnotherClass extends SomeClass {
    someMethod(param1: string) { ... }
}
```

Also I've got a third class that uses instance of one of these classes as generic e.g.

```
class ThirdClass<T extends SomeClass> {
   instanceClass: T;
}
```

So I'm getting an error that someMethod in `AnotherClass` is not compatible with `SomeClass`, to solve the problem I should make an overload for `someMethod` in `SomeClass` :

```
someMethod(param1: string); // <-- overload
someMethod(param1: string; param2?: string) { ... }
```

Is there any other way to say TS that everything is ok?

Comment: Cannot replicate: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKD2BbApgYXFaBvAUNfESyAssgC4AW8AJgBQAOYATmIgIwBc0EZTAlgDsA5gBpojFogBMAfi49+wgJTZoAXxwacoSDACCA+JWRN0u6MgAeZZAOowEKM5lz4CRUpRoNmrTt15BIRUsfA0tHUwAFQo+JmpnCAAeKItrW3s4IkSAPmw8fGB4AQUAV2AyeCYGUoAjED5gaEEeMAFgNAwILiiQgrcWsjaOxIA6QhRPKjoAIhseGaV+8KA)